# Python - split a list of dicts into individual dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, network-analysis

I'm using the HITS algorithm for Social Network Analysis. The use of this algorithm produces two different measures: hub-score and authority-score. A list is produced containing two dictionaries based on these metrics, with one dictionary having an index of 0, the other 1.

How can I remove the overarching list to get two separate dictionaries? Code and output is as follows:

```
G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist('data.csv', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
HITS_scores = list(nx.hits(G))

Output:
List = Index     Type      Value
       0         dict      {'node1': 0.023, 'node3': 0.017.....'node17': 0.045}
       1         dict      {'node2': 0.042, 'node4': 0.002.....'node16': 0.032}

Desired Output:
hub_score =      dict      {'node1': 0.023, 'node3': 0.017.....'node17': 0.045}
auth_score =     dict      {'node2': 0.042, 'node4': 0.002.....'node16': 0.032}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

PS I've tried looking for an answer however have been unable to find a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can unpack iterables with an assignment to a list of targets, like this

```
hub_score, auth_score = nx.hits(G)
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll remember this trick in future. Thanks for the help, I'll mark your answer as correct when the time-period passes.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
hub_score = HITS_scores[0]
auth_score = HITS_scores[1]
```

?

You could as well not generate the list in the first place by writing `list(nx.hits(G))` but instead proccess your data in some other way.

Comment: Gilch's answer is slightly simpler, however this also works perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The answer gilch provided should do the trick. However, if you were stuck with a list, you could pull out the individual dict entries and assign them like this:

```
hub_score = HITS_scores[0]
auth_score = HITS_scores[1]
```

Comment: You and Arno-Nymous think very similarly! Thanks for the extra advice.